# sc.addFile throwing error=2, No such file or directory in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run an R script buy piping out an RDD to an Rscript using Spark's pipe(). I am using sc.addFile() to copy the Rscript to the executor's memory.

```
sc.addFile(rScript) and using SparkFiles.get(rName) to get the file name.
```

While running the job cluster mode, I am getting below error

```
Cannot run program "/data/tmp/spark-b8b8053e-0110-4ddb-91a3-
ae6f0f633c68/userFiles-78ed11c0-483b-4615-88eb-
8d1c97571997/RSCRIPT_NAME.R": error=2, No such file 
or directory
```

But the file is getting copied to /data/tmp/spark-b8b8053e-0110-4ddb-91a3-
    ae6f0f633c68/userFiles-78ed11c0-483b-4615-88eb-
    8d1c97571997 location.

Not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to execute it as

```
rdd.pipe("scriptName.R")
```

Please add "./" before you call the script.

```
rdd.pipe("./scriptName.R")
```